# rails image resizing with carrierwave and minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

I have a rails app, profile images are uploaded with carrierwave and processed with minimagick.

This is what I used to have:

```
version :base_thumb do
  process :resize_to_fit => [85, 85]
end
```

I just realized some profile pics are distorted. People's heads on the pic are stretched vertically. I guess this is caused since I only used the `resize_to_fit` method.

I came up with the following, but it doesn't work.  With this code I get `undefined method "process"` error. I also had to add a new version (`use_thumb`).

```
version :base_thumb do
  process :resizing => [85, 85]
end

version :user_thumb do
  process :resizing => [40, 40]
end

def resizing(h, w)
  manipulate! do |img|
    if img.width > img.height
      process :resize_to_fill => [h, w]
    else
      process :resize_to_fit => [h, w]
    end
  end
end
```

My question are the following:

- Is this issue caused because I only use `resize_to_fit` method?
- If so how can I make my `resizing` method work?

UPDATE:

My goal here is to display profile images with no distortion/ whitespace. The height/width ratio of all my images is 1:1. If sby uploads something like 2:1 or 1:2 ratio, I still would like to display it as 1:1 without distortion and whitespace around it.

I'm not sure if it's enough to use `resize_to_fit`, `resize_to_fill` and `resize_to_limit` versions, or I have to manipulate the image with cropping etc.

As I see in most of the rails apps, guys are simply using `resize_to_fit` or `resize_to_fill` and not having any problems with the ratio, somehow their images are always displayed nicely.

Comment: if my answer solved your problem you should let others know! if not posting your solution is great also!

Comment: Tall Paul, I'm checking out soon and will mark your answer checked if everything goes according to plan.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the same ratio of the picture to resize it without distorting it then you should read [this](http://maxivak.com/crop-and-resize-an-image-using-minimagick-ruby-on-rails/).

If you are just trying to get the middle of the picture with the same crop you should read [this](http://www.codeblog.it/en/snippet/ruby/2012/08/27/how-scale-center-and-crop-image-ruby-and-mini-magic).

Hope that helps

Comment: Tall Paul, I've updated my question. Could you take a look at it? I'm pretty confused. Went thru bunch of articles including what u recommended, but couldn't decide what to use. What you recommended seems to be kinda complex solution compared to what I've seen in most of the rails apps. I don't wanna do anything fancy here, just wanna have my images properly displayed. I also checked out a bunch of carrierwave videos and somehow uploaded images never get distorted.